# .splice() array with array of non-sequential indexes - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice, array-splice

I have an array like this

```
Array['one','two','three','four','five']
```

and I have an array like this

```
Array['2','4','0']
```

indicating the indexes of the elements in the first array I wish to remove or `.splice()` so the resulting array would look like this

```
Array['two','four']  // <--- note no undefined positions
```

If you try and loop through the indexes and just do a splice for each one, after the first splice your indexes change according to the element that was removed.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start splicing the indexes from the array in reverse order. i.e. Loop from the length of array to 0.

First splice index 4 and then index 2.

EDIT: As you mentioned the indexes array need not be in same order, you can sort the indexes array in ascending order and then implement the above logic.

Comment: +1 for being clever, but there is no guarantee the "indexes" array will be in a given ordering.  I'll update the question to make that clear.

Comment: @jondavidjohn - No issues. Just sort the indexes array to make it in ascending order. Updated my answer too. Hope this helps :)